# How to use usecols elements which are regex rather than strings?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I created a script to go over the needed data, using pandas. 
I'm now receiving more files that I need to go over, and sadly these files do not have the same headers.

For example I have placed in my list of columns to use 'id_num' and in some of the files it appears as 'num_id'.

Is it possible to still use the usecols list I created, and allow certain elements in it to "connect" with different header strings, for example by using regex?

Comment: if the data is same, you can map it, else use a fuzzywuzzy match

Comment: After looking at fuzzywuzzy I fear it might be to haphazard, but mapping sounds intriguing. What did you mean by that?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551173/mapping-2-dataframes-and-replacing-header-of-matched-values-in-target-dataframe although I am not sure about your exact requirement but felt this might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the `usecols` keyword in `pd.read_csv` (or some analogous pandas reading)? I'm sure you've gathered that pandas can't do a regex search on a dataframe *before* it even read the dataframe so I'm fairly certain doing a regex search with the `usecols` keyword isn't feasible.

However, after you read the csv into a dataframe (let's name it `df` for the sake of the example), you could very easily filter the columns of interest using regexes.

for example, suppose your new dataframe is loaded into `df`:

```
potential_columns = ['num_id', 'id_num']

df_cols = [col for col in df.columns if re.search('|'.join(potential_columns), col)]
```

You could list all potential columns you want to search for with `potential_columns`. Then using `join` create one massive regex search. Then use a list comprehension to aggregate all valid columns in `df.columns`. Once that's done you can finish this process by calling:

```
df = df[df_cols]
```

Dealing with duplicate columns, creating clever keywords to search for is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that by loading the unwanted columns and then dropping them, the whole operation takes more time, which for large datasets could be something you'd want to avoid. Regarding the "regex" type, you can get something like that with a callable. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116439/2316433).